# OpenGLES 2.0 fragment shader alpha fail?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I would expect my texture to disappear completely with the following fragment shader:

```
varying mediump vec2 text_coord_out;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, text_coord_out);
    gl_FragColor.w *= 0.0;
}
```

. . .it doesn't.  I've also tried gl_FragColor.a.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 9):

OMG...I totally fixed this.  Fragment shader looks like this:

```
varying mediump float text_alpha_out;
varying mediump vec2 text_coord_out;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, text_coord_out);
    gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * text_alpha_out;
}
```

and my blending looks like this:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: You can call "gl_fragColor=" only once per shader program. Second calls are ignored.

Comment: Can you absolutely call gl_fragColor = more than once.  Second calls are not ignored.  I do it all the time.

Answer (score 7):

Use `gl_fragColor =` only once

1. perform all operations on different variables like another `vec4` in this case
2. you can use this as the output, like:

---

```
vec4 red = vec4( 1,0,0,1 );
gl_fragColor = red;
```

Comment: I doubt it. Second call to `gl_FragColor` is not ignored in my experiment.

Answer (score 4):

Why should it disappear? The alpha value of the output color has no meaning unless you give it a meaning. Typically, that means using some form of [blending](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending). Note that the link describes desktop OpenGL; the GL ES equivalent works much the same way, but desktop GL may have more features than ES.

Comment: Thanks.  This has gotten me closer.  I've gone from `
'
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
'

to:

'
glBlendEquationSeparate(GL_FUNC_ADD, GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA,
                        GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,
                        GL_SRC_ALPHA,
                        GL_ZERO);
'

but reintroduces:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060578/iphone-opengles-2-0-text-texture-w-strange-border-not-stroke-issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060578/iphone-opengles-2-0-text-texture-w-strange-border-not-stroke-issue)

Comment: The problem seems to be I have textures with premultiplied alpha. . .which doesn't work with GL_SRC_ALPHA as the first argument to blend functions. . .but if I use GL_ONE, then blending just doesn't happen in the shader. . .Thoughts?

Comment: @datafatmunger: Blending isn't supposed to happen in the shader. So I'm not sure what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
gl_FragColor.w = 0;
```

should work. Probably *= operation bewilders GLSL compiler.